# WordPress installation under subdirectory all pages except gives 404

Tags: magento-1.9, htaccess, wordpress

I have a Magento installation in base directory and WordPress installation in my sub directory. When I open the home page of WordPress it opens normally but when I go to any sub-page/post of WordPress it gives 404 not found error from Magento. I've tried almost everything on the `.htaccess` file but didn't find the solution. I also tried the solution from [Magento under WordPress as subdirectory not working](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58658/magento-under-wordpress-as-subdirectory-not-working) but that doesn't work for me.

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
    php_flag session.auto_start off
    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    SSLOptions StdEnvVars
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
AddDefaultCharset Off
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
<Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files cron.php>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

and `.htaccess` for WordPress:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /blog/*
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is down to your rewrite base having the * at the end, as per [How to add another web app to a subdirectory within Magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53756/how-to-add-another-web-app-to-a-subdirectory-within-magento) (although that's quite old)

I suspect that you are using Apache, and if this is not a duplicate of that question, it would be better to ask this of Apache experts rather than Magento experts.

(Sorry, can't comment yet, so had to answer...)